# LAMP 403 Forbidden after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: permissions, apache2, lamp

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04, my localhost started throwing 403 errors.
The default `DocumentRoot` and `Directories` are both equal to one another, and the permissions on the default folder (and all sub-folders) is 755.

After applying the fix suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1233301) I was able to regain access to localhost/phpymyadmin however I still can't get other files to work.

Comment: NOTE: The ownership of my default directory is also set to my current user.

Comment: please use the "green check-mark" to indicate which answer answered the question, instead of using solved.

Comment: Agreed however there is a two day delay before you can approve your own answer and in the mean time this question does not require additional attention.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

The `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` had been reset and therefore the listed Directory was reset to `/var/www` which mismatched the directory listed in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf` file which had not been reset.

**Solution:**

To access phpmyadmin add the following line to the end of apache2.conf (as detailed in the [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin))

`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

To access other localhost files, what worked for my was changing the references in my `default.conf` file(s) back to apache2's `/var/www/` and creating a symlink between my desired default file and `/var/www/`

`sudo ln -s /DEFAULT_DIRECTORY/ /var/`

Comment: It's not recommended to do modifications in `apache2.conf` for this specific problem. In an upgrade, your changes will most likely be gone.

Comment: Thanks for the input Dan, if I undo my changes I'm back to getting 403s, could you possibly suggest an alternative?

Comment: It depends. For example if you are adding virtual hosts, you should create a new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<some-file>.conf` and you can enable/disable that virtual host with `a2ensite <some-file>`/`a2dissite <some-file>` respectively. (They stand for Apache2 ENable SITE and Apache2 DISable SITE). Same goes for modules in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/<some-module>.conf` and other configs in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/<some-module>.conf`.

Comment: As a fix for the default directory I simply changed all references back to `/var/www/` (the default apache.conf value) and created a symlink between my desired default directory and `/var/www/` however the problem persisted for PHPMyAdmin. I checked on the official phpmyadmin [doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin) and they also recommended editing the apache.conf file and can't seem to find an alternative.